# ProgrammingError at /catalog/

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

So I'm trying to open my Heroku app website. After pushing the files from a git repository to my git heroku repository, I open the website and get this error message.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://chimpbooks.herokuapp.com/catalog/

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "catalog_book" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "catalog_book"
                                          ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/catalog/views.py", line 11, in index
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 515, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 500, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /catalog/
Exception Value: relation "catalog_book" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "catalog_book"
```

Hoping someone can help me figure this out! Hoping to add more books to this website and get it finished soon. Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you run the `migrate` command on Heroku?

Comment: PS it looks like you have debug mode on. It's important for security reasons to have that OFF in production! You can still see the cause of any errors in the Heroku logs.

Comment: I set Debug to False and pushed the repository again, but this time I got a Server Error (500)

Comment: What database did you connect to? If you didn't configure any external database, django has the default DB configuration and that isn't persistent in the storage meaning migrating is of no use too...Use heroku's postgres database

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I’m new to heroku

Comment: The 500 error is indeed what you'll see for any error with Debug false - the full details will be in the logs. It's less convenient for the developer, which is why we have Debug mode on in development - but in production you don't want to show everyone those details of your code.

Comment: So....how do I fix it?